# In pose mode my armature is curving instead of moving in a line why?

Tags: armature, bones, pose-mode

I just want my armature to move in a straight direction but for some reason the root bone is moving in an arc formation to the right as it goes along the animation path in pose mode.[image]

Comment: It is hard to judge from just a picture, but is your root bone parented to another object that moves?

Comment: Well, the armature is parented to the follow path constraint but even that object isn't moving.